# how to center registration of loaded image

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following function to load external images into the stage but when I try to zoom the image by scaling width and height it doesn't get bigger from the center.

What should I do or use to make images bigger from center?

```js
function resimYukle(ad:String,xx:Number,yy:Number,isim:String)
{
    var resim:URLRequest = new URLRequest(yolum+"images/matematikmodulu/sayilar/"+ad+".png");
    var img:Loader = new Loader();
    img.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
    img.load(resim);
}

function imageLoaded(e:Event):void
{  
    e.target.content.smoothing = true;
    if(isim.indexOf("ksayi")>=0)
    {
        img.width = img.width * 0.07;
        img.height = img.height * 0.07;
    }
    else
    {
        img.width = img.width * 0.13;
        img.height = img.height * 0.13;
    }
    img.x = xx -(img.width / 2);
    img.y = yy -(img.height / 2);
    img.name = isim;
    addChild(img);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use another function to center registration points, fortunately ı have a function that solves the problem. I inserted the function and called it when image loaded.

```js
function resimYukle(ad:String,xx:Number,yy:Number,isim:String)
  {
   var resim:URLRequest = new URLRequest(yolum+"images/matematikmodulu/sayilar/"+ad+".png");
   var img:Loader = new Loader();
   img.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
   img.load(resim);

   function imageLoaded(e:Event):void
   {
    
    e.target.content.smoothing = true;
    setRegPoint(img, img.width / 2, img.height / 2);
    if(isim.indexOf("ksayi")>=0)
    {
    img.width = img.width * 0.07;
    img.height = img.height * 0.07;
    }
    else
    {
     img.width = img.width * 0.13;
    img.height = img.height * 0.13;
    }
    img.x = xx -(img.width / 2);
    img.y = yy -(img.height / 2);
    img.name = isim;
    addChild(img);


   }
  }

function setRegPoint(obj:DisplayObjectContainer, newX:Number, newY:Number):void
  {
   var bounds:Rectangle = obj.getBounds(obj.parent);
   var currentRegX:Number = obj.x - bounds.left;
   var currentRegY:Number = obj.y - bounds.top;
   var xOffset:Number = newX - currentRegX;
   var yOffset:Number = newY - currentRegY;
   obj.x +=  xOffset;
   obj.y +=  yOffset;
   for (var i:int = 0; i < obj.numChildren; i++)
   {
    obj.getChildAt(i).x -=  xOffset;
    obj.getChildAt(i).y -=  yOffset;
   }
  }
```